# download with resume a file using curl

Tags: php, curl

Does anyone know how to download a file using curl and PHP and supports resume. and link to a tutorial or code demonstration will be good. I'm using this code now but it doesn't support resume, and i don't know how to handle headers. help will be appreciated

```
$start_range = 0; 
$url = URL to remote file 
$end_range = $filesize; 
while($start_range <= $end_range) { 
    if(($start_range + 9999999) > $end_range) $range = $start_range.'-'; 
    else $range = $start_range.'-'.($start_range + 9999999); 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refurl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,$range); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1'); 
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    $start_range +=10000000; 
    flush(); 
        ob_flush() 
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://www.ankur.com/blog/106/php/resume-http-downloads-php-curl-fsockopen/